# Move git-lfs files from bitbucket to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I am moving my source code from `Bitbucket` cloud to `Gitlab`. I imported the project from `Bitbucket` into `Gitlab` using Gitlab's `Import` feature. My bitbucket repo also has git-lfs objects. How do I import them?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this with a Github-to-Gitlab-EE migration. Assuming that Bitbucket is using git-lfs then it should work the same way. Here's what I did:

```
ORG=myorg
REPONAME=myrepo
OLD_REPO=github.com
NEW_REPO=gitlab.mydomain.com
echo "Old repo=git@${OLD_REPO}:${ORG}/${REPONAME}"
echo "New repo=git@${NEW_REPO}:${ORG}/${REPONAME}"

git clone --bare git@${OLD_REPO}:${ORG}/${REPONAME}.git
cd ${REPONAME}.git
git lfs fetch --all
git config lfs.https://${NEW_REPO}/${ORG}/${REPONAME}.git/info/lfs.locksverify true
git lfs push --all git@${NEW_REPO}:${ORG}/${REPONAME}.git
git push --all git@${NEW_REPO}:${ORG}/${REPONAME}.git
```