# On fresh gitlab repo I get this error: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all"

Tags: git, gitlab

I just set up a new gitlab group and a fresh private gitlab repo in that group. I am attempting to create a project from an existing folder.

#### The problem

I deleted the .git folder containing all of the git history from the existing folder. Then I created the gitlab repository, executed

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:my_group_username/my-repo.git
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

I got this error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

#### What I have tried

- I checked to make sure the master branch isn't protected. It's not.
- I checked to see what webhooks are configured. There are none.
- I tried pushing to a new branch, not named master
- I checked my user configuration with

```
git config list
```

and my user info is configured as expected.

- I deleted the repo, recreated it, and tried to push. Same issue.
- I checked to make sure that my gitlab user is configured as a contributor. I am the owner of the project.
- I even created a Github repo in the same way, and was able to push my commits to that repo without any issues.

Any ideas what might be causing this error?

### Edit - git push command and output:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

```
Enumerating objects: 31, done.
Counting objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (31/31), 78.73 KiB | 8.75 MiB/s, done.
Total 31 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
To gitlab.com:dellacortelab/prospr.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:dellacortelab/prospr.git'
```

Looking at this again, it looks like there is an issue with LFS (large file storage), but the repository is only 1.5 Mb in size. It originally did have some large files, but I deleted them before deleting the .git folder, so I don't know how gitlab would know about them.

### Update:

There was a reference to LFS files in my .gitattributes file, so I deleted the .gitattributes file and the directory that it referenced, but I still got the same error.

Removed .gitattributes file:

```
potts/plmDCA_asymmetric/plmDCA_asymmetric.ctf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Comment: You say gitlab in the text and title, but github in your remote url. Which is it?

Comment: Were the fresh new repos created with README or LICENSE or `.gitignore`?

Comment: Is the remote repository completely empty without any existing branch like `master` or `main`?

Comment: Please show the entire output from `git push`

Comment: It is gitlab - the url I posted was copied from my later experiment where I added a github repo to see if I could push to github (I could). I corrected the question to have the correct url.

Comment: The fresh gitlab repo was not created with a README or license. The github repo did have a license.

Comment: I didn't explicitly create a main or master branch, but I'm not sure how to verify that they exist - there is no drop-down menu with the names of the branches in a fresh gitlab repo.

Comment: If you want to overwrite the history, you could try a force push (add `-f` to the `push` command)

Comment: I just tried force pushing - same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The final solution: purging all references to LFS files from git history

- I removed the `.gitattributes` file as well as the file that it referenced: `potts/plmDCA_asymmetric/plmDCA_asymmetric.ctf`, and commited again.
- Still couldn't push
- So I removed the `.git` directory, reinitialized the git repository, and pushed.
- It worked!

There are probably more nuanced ways to purge the git history of referenced to LFS, but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have deleted the `.git` folder. So, apparently the working copy was obtained from another repository. The problem seems to be that not all of the files tracked by `git lfs` were actually downloaded. By deleting the `.git` folder, you have lost all that information.

What you should have done instead:

While the previous repository is still setup as remote `origin`, ensure that all files tracked by lfs are downloaded by issuing the command

```
git lfs fetch --all
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734558/2311167).

Only then switch to the new repo. I would suggest not deleting the `.git` folder, but adding it as another remote, say

```
git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:my_group_username/my-repo.git
```

The procedure described in the answer cited above pushes the files tracked by lfs explicitely with

```
git lfs push --all gitlab
```

In my case, this was not necessary. Once all files tracked by lfs have been fetched, a simple

```
git push gitlab master
```

should do the job. However, this replicates the entire history to the new repo and this is not what you want. If you want to get rid of the history, you can squash the history to one single commit. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189560/2311167) on how to do this.